# argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Tags: python, list, arguments, pygame, iteration

Hi i'm making a basic raycast engine so i think it would be nice to start with the minimap but the problem is that my class map ask for a mapGrid in the constructor and when i pass it python give me this error `argument 2 to map() must support iteration`

This is the code:
Main part

```
import pygame
def map(object):
    def __init__(self,grid,scale):
        self.grid= grid
        self.mapWidth= len(grid[0]) #Number of map blocks
        self.mapHeight= len(grid) 
        self.miniMapScale= scale #How many pixels to draw a map block
        self.miniWidth= self.mapWidth * self.miniMapScale #Size of the minimap
        self.miniHeight= self.mapHeight * self.miniMapScale

        self.rectGrid= grid

        for y in range(self.mapHeight):
            for x in range(self.mapWidth):
                self.rectGrid[y][x]= pygame.Rect(x,y,self.miniWidth,self.miniHeight)

    def blitMiniMap():
        pass
```

Data file

```
mapGrid= [
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1]
]

size = [640, 480]
```

map class

```
import pygame
def map(object):
    def __init__(self,grid,scale):
        self.grid= grid
        self.mapWidth= len(grid[0]) #Number of map blocks
        self.mapHeight= len(grid) 
        self.miniMapScale= scale #How many pixels to draw a map block
        self.miniWidth= self.mapWidth * self.miniMapScale #Size of the minimap
        self.miniHeight= self.mapHeight * self.miniMapScale

        self.rectGrid= grid

        for y in range(self.mapHeight):
            for x in range(self.mapWidth):
                self.rectGrid[y][x]= pygame.Rect(x,y,self.miniWidth,self.miniHeight)

    def blitMiniMap():
        pass
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you had to post the same code twice? There's a builtin function called `map`, _it_ has two arguments to pass to it

Answer (score 2):

`map` is a python built-in function. Using `map` as a function name thus leads to confusion, so you should consider renaming your `map` function to something different.

Also, what you call "map class" only defines a function, not a class. Did you perhaps confuse `def` with `class` in the class definition?